# Bottle labeler suggestions

Tags: bottle, labels

my dad and uncle are homebrewers and they desperately need a labeler. They've talked about getting one before but have more important things to get first in order to perfect their beer. So for Christmas, I'd like to get them one so they can stop using paper and glue. On bottling day, they bottle about 100 bottles and they bottle probably once every 2 weeks. If anyone has any suggestions as to which labeler would work best for them, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Are they looking for fancy labels or just a simple label that indicated what the beer is?  There are plenty of simple label maker type printers out there that print on vinyl like stickers. Something like a brother P-touch.  But fancy labels are different.

Comment: Please mention how much money you are willing to pay.  Some professionnal labeler can cost about 600$, like this one [Bottle Labeler on amazon](http://www.amazon.com/START-International-LAB01-Manual-Applicator/dp/B005C6DC4S)

Comment: are they looking at applying labels they print or a commercially-made spool of them?

Comment: see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2se3gUTZgF4

Answer (score 2):

For fancy reusable labels you could try [Grogtags](http://www.grogtag.com/).

With those you design it on their website then they print and ship to you.
Not a label maker, but its the only thing I could think of that's like what you described.
Most at home labelers are paper based.

Comment: Grogtags are awesome, but a little pricey IMO. However, it is the least fuss way to get custom labels on your bottles.

Comment: I wonder if you could simply by the same type of vinyl-like stuff they use but in sheet form with a white frost on it.  Then they could simply write on each bottle and reuse.

Comment: @brewchez, I use that for my kegs. :) However, for bottles it might be a problem as the whiteboard marker writings would come off too easily. For instance, if you move the bottle out of the way to get to another one, or if you put the bottles in an ice bath.

Comment: They design their own labels on the computer and use glue to put them on the bottles which makes for a slimy mess when the bottles condense after taking them out of the fridge. I'm looking for one that will eliminate the slimy mess but will still let them design their own labels. And the less expensive, the better because I am a poor college kid. I appreciate all of your help so far and I'll definitely look into the suggestions you've posted already!

Answer (score 2):

**I can suggest a small Zebra printer.**

There are many models that can print on removable labels of 1" up to 4" wide.  It usually comes with a software that allows you to design a label and print as many as you want (a roll will contain about 800 labels).  The price would vary depending on the model (for about 200$ to 400$ you should get a good printer).
Some more expensive models will even cut and peel the labels for you.

Since there are so many models and options, I would contact a vendor to get the best printer for this specific work.  Don't forget to buy removable labels, the permanent ones won't come off even after soaking...  You can take a look at their website for details : [www.zebra.com](http://www.zebra.com)

Comment: There are loads of labels that you can choose from, some of them are waterproof and prints using thermal paper, so you save on ink. However; be careful on how sticky they are! Some of the labels are made to be stuck on the outside of a shipping container - think sun, water, heat, storm resistant stickiness! Those are extremely difficult to remove and not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [www.BeerClings.com](http://www.beerclings.com).  Again, not a label machine but the labels work awesome.  I prefer them to grogtag, they last longer.  Sounds like they deal in quite a bit of volume.  If they are asking for the bottles back at all, this would be a great option as they could slap the labels on the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

VKPAK can provide labeling solutions for various wine bottles, from 18ml to 18 liter round bottles, conical bottles, square bottles, etc. We provide one-stop labeling solutions, whether you need to label a few hundred bottles a day, thousands of bottles or even tens of thousands of bottles; whether your bottles need one label, or two or more labels, whether your labels are common self-adhesive rolls, or sheets of label paper, VKPAK can provide you with the most suitable labeling solutions.

read more: [Wine Bottle Labeler](https://www.vkpak.com/wine-bottle-labeler.html)